# Keeping the Dominion of Newfoundland independent

Tags: internal-consistency, politics, alternate-history

The [dominion of Newfoundland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominion_of_Newfoundland) was a part of the British commonwealth from 1907 to 1949 before becoming a part of Canada. They served in both world wars and lasted longer than any independent American state having been an independent nation for 42 years, but could they remain independent?

[image]

The land that the could have and did support them, but they were economically weak. What is the smallest thing I can change in history to allow for Newfoundland to exist well into the 21st century?

Comment: I think this question is very, very difficult to answer, because there's no _one_ event which would have triggered their joining Canada in the first place. Rather, it was a series of complex social, economic, and political factors which worked together. And I doubt anyone here would be able to answer that question to any realistic standard. To me, this seems either too broad, or opinion based. Might not even fit the definition of Worldbuilding, now that I think about it.

Comment: @AndreiROM hate to break it to you, but alternate history is undeniably a kind of worldbuilding

Comment: I agree that this is fundamentally on topic but I think it needs more constraining...its really broad at this point.

Comment: @TinyTrEs-2b I hate to break it to you, but "alternate history" questions are nearly always too broad or opinion based (or both) - they may be worldbuilding but they're typically a bad type of question for the stack exchange format.

Comment: @Aify Alternate history gets a bad rep from JohnDwailey's broad questions, not because the genre is bad for worldbuilding. Some of the sites best questions are alternate history based: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-history?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: @TinyTrEs-2b There's 266 questions are tagged with AH. Less than 50 of those are "good questions" (if we define a good question via vote count) - even on the first page, there are only 20 questions above 20 votes. That means that just over 7.5% of the AH questions are "good questions" - fully supporting my description of "alternate history questions being *nearly always too broad/opinion based/both*. If we further increase the metric to "top questions" as defined by 50 votes or more, you end up with 1.1% rate. If we look at the weapons tag, for example, and use the same metrics...

Comment: ... the top question rate almost doubles, and the "good question" rate jumps up to 13.1%. Consider that there are also only 150 "top questions" (exactly at the moment of posting, how convenient), the difference again becomes apparent - only 1.3% of the top questions belong to the AH tag, while weapons holds 4.6%. We could also look at the number of closed questions per category, but my gut tells me that the results would only further support my suspicions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dominion of Newfoundland existed as an independent Dominion for so long essentially because it was so small and poor that no one was really interested in it. Indeed, getting Newfoundland into Confederation was so contentious (by both sides; the Dominion of Canada was not too keen on absorbing a poor and debt ridden Newfoundland, while many Newfoundlanders to this day claim the referendum was rigged) that it took all the considerable political skill of [Joey Smallwood](https://infogalactic.com/info/Joey_Smallwood) to engineer the feat.

The British Empire was not particularly interested in Newfoundland (the port of Halifax had been the major British port in North America for centuries), Canada's commercial interest in Newfoundland was looked upon with suspicion by many Newfoundlander's and the other alternative, association with the United States, while having some support in Newfoundland, was opposed by the Empire and the Dominion of Canada.

The most likely means of ensuring the Dominion of Newfoundland remains independent is to simply allow inertia to take its course, without a Joey Smallwood to drive a movement for joining the Dominion to Canada. Canada is content to allow Newfoundland to remain independent, so long as the Americans stay out, London has more pressing issues on its plate and most Newfoundlanders are content with the Status Quo.